# How to find ALL substrings in string using starting and ending words arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, substring

I've spent my last 4 hours figuring out how to ... I got to ask for your help now.

I'm trying to extract from a text multiple substring match my starting_words_array and ending_words_array.

```
$str = "Do you see that ? Indeed, I can see that, as well as this." ;
$starting_words_array = array('do','I');
$ending_words_array = array('?',',');
```

**expected output** : array ([0] => 'Do you see that ?' [1] => 'I can see that,')

I manage to write a first function that can find the first substring matching one of both arrays items. But i'm not able to find how to loop it in order to get all the substring matching my requirement.

```
   function SearchString($str, $starting_words_array, $ending_words_array ) {
   forEach($starting_words_array as $test) {
     $pos = strpos($str, $test);
     if ($pos===false) continue;
     $found = [];
     forEach($ending_words_array  as $test2) {
        $posStart = $pos+strlen($test);
        $pos2 = strpos($str, $test2, $posStart);
        $found[] = ($pos2!==false) ? $pos2 : INF;
     }
     $min = min($found);
     if ($min !== INF)
        return substr($str,$pos,$min-$pos) .$str[$min];
  }
  return '';
}
```

Do you guys have any idea about how to achieve such thing ?

Comment: Using `return` inside your loop construct makes very little sense - of course with that, you are “out of there”, as soon as the first match is found. You need something like, collect your found matches in an array, and then return that at the end of the function.

Comment: Do you want to find this for all combinations of start and end? So also for start = 'do' and end = ','. That would still deliver the "Do you see that? Indeed, I can see that,".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benni answer is best way to go - but let just point out the problem in your code if you want to fix those:

1. `strpos` is not case sensitive and find also part of words so you need to changes your `$starting_words_array = array('do','I');` to `$starting_words_array = array('Do','I ');`
2. When finding a substring you use return which exit the function so you want find any other substring. In order to fix that you can define `$res = [];` at the beginning of the function and replace `return substr($str,$pos,...` with `$res[] = substr($str,$pos,...` and at the end return the `$res` var.

You can see example in [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/ZU3Qc) - in that example you get the output you wanted

Answer (score 3):

I use preg_match for my solution. However, the start and end strings must be escaped with preg_quote. Without that, the solution will be wrong.

```
function searchString($str, $starting_words_array, $ending_words_array ) {
   $resArr = [];
   forEach($starting_words_array as $i => $start) {
     $end = $ending_words_array[$i] ?? "";
     $regEx = '~'.preg_quote($start,"~").".*".preg_quote($end,"~").'~iu';
     if(preg_match_all($regEx,$str,$match)){
       $resArr[] = $match[0];
     }
   }
return $resArr;
}
```

The result is what the questioner expects.

If the expressions can occur more than once, preg_match_all must also be used. The regex must be modify.

```
function searchString($str, $starting_words_array, $ending_words_array ) {
   $resArr = [];
   forEach($starting_words_array as $i => $start) {
     $end = $ending_words_array[$i] ?? "";
     $regEx = '~'.preg_quote($start,"~").".*?".preg_quote($end,"~").'~iu';
     if(preg_match_all($regEx,$str,$match)){
       $resArr = array_merge($resArr,$match[0]);
     }
   }
return $resArr;
}
```

The resut for the second variant:

```
array (
  0 => "Do you see that ?",
  1 => "Indeed,",
  2 => "I can see that,",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely use regex and `preg_match_all()`. I won't give you a full working code example here but I will outline the necessary steps.

First, build a regex from your start-end-pairs like that:

```
$parts = array_map(
    function($start, $end) {
        return $start . '.+' . $end;
    },
    $starting_words_array,
    $ending_words_array
);
$regex = '/' . join('|', $parts) . '/i';
```

The `/i` part means case insensitive search. Some characters like the `?` have a special purpose in regex, so you need to extend above function in order to escape it properly.
You can test your final regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Then use `preg_match_all()` to extract your substrings:

```
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches); // $matches is passed by reference, no need to declare it first

print_r($matches);
```

The exact structure of your $matches array will be slightly different from what you asked for but you will be able to extract your desired data from it